# React component renders before I can set src of image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, rendering

I have this application that flashes a series of cards. Some have questions with text. No problem there obviously. But the image source is being retrieved from firebase. On each render I check if it has a question with text, or with an image and if it has an image I query the database for the downloadURL and insert that as the source. If I insert it hard coded it works fine, if I console log the response it's accurate. My problem is I believe that the component renders before I can insert the source dynamically. Code is below. And yes, I know with that many conditionals it looks like a christmas tree and is probably really bad practice.
To save some reading I'll splice it where I make the request here...

```
useEffect(() => {
    if ("imageHolder" in active) {
      const asyncFunc = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setImage(true);
        await storageRef
          .child(active.imageHolder)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(function (url) {
            imageSrc = url;
            console.log("url returns ", url);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      };
      asyncFunc();
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [active, getQuestions, correctAnswer]);
```

And where I insert it here

```
 ) : image ? (
          loading ? (
            <h1>Loading</h1>
          ) : (
            <img alt="" src={imageSrc} className="d-inline-block align-top" />
          )
        ) : (
          <h3>{active.question}</h3>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="answerGrid">
        {loading ? (
```

Thanks for any advice at all. And stay healthy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful to see the rest of the code, but given the provided snippets, I'm assuming the problem is with how the `imageSrc` variable is getting set.

Have you tried managing the `imageSrc` as state? E.g.

```
const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('')

// then use setImageSrc after getting the url
await storageRef
          .child(active.imageHolder)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(function (url) {
            setImageSrc(url)
            console.log("url returns ", url);
          })
```

Comment: I've been trying to think of how to make it rerender for 45 minutes and before I even tried it I knew that you nailed it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think simple decision to this will be adding a logical "or" operator in src
like this

```
<img alt="" src={imageSrc || ''} className="d-inline-block align-top" />
```